# VS 2017 failed publish container to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-2017, aws-sdk, aws-cli, docker-container

I have a simple web application and trying to publich to ESC.

VS throws below error while publishing...

Unknown error executing command: Failed to locate docker CLI executable. Make sure the docker CLI is installed in the environment PATH.
   at Amazon.ECS.Tools.DockerCLIWrapper..ctor(IToolLogger logger, String workingDirectory)
   at Amazon.ECS.Tools.Commands.PushDockerImageCommand.d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Amazon.Common.DotNetCli.Tools.Commands.BaseCommand`1.d__9.MoveNext()

I have installed AWS CLI Version 1 and added environment variable.

But still getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ash, the error clearly points to the problem.

Failed to locate docker CLI executable

AWS CLI just provides ability to login to ECR for pushing the docker. To build and deploy, you still need the docker client. You have not installed the docker client for building/pushing the Docker. Refer the documentation at: [Install Docker](https://docs.docker.com/install/) . In case you have already installed it, make sure you have its binary path set in your environment variables.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and time, that fixed my issue